# How to seperate output log of a build step in teamcity

Tags: python, teamcity

I have a python script that builds 100s of libs and apps concurrently which looks like one big build step in teamcity. But I would like to make each build look like a seperate build step in teamcity or at least be able to mark when one of the builds fail.

Is there a way to either programatically setup teamcity to call these builds or format the output of the python controlled build to look like seperate steps when viewing the teamcity job status log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use some special message inside your build script to report a message.

Like this:

```
##teamcity[message text='<message text>' errorDetails='<error details>' status='<status value>']
```

or opening/closing blocks

Block opening:

```
##teamcity[blockOpened name='<blockName>' description='<this is the description of blockName>']
```

Block closing:

```
##teamcity[blockClosed name='<blockName>']
```

It's enough to send it as standard output of your script.

A complete list of possible messages [here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity).